# comma + when / in which and and at the moment

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw a girl studying at a coffee shop and I thought she was beautiful.And a couple of weeks after I'd seen her studying at the coffee shop,

> 1. I saw her dancing really hard at a club, **in which** I thought she was so attractive.
> 2. I saw her dancing really hard at a club, **when** I thought she was so attractive.
> 3. I saw her dancing really hard at a club **and at the moment,** I thought she was so attractive.

I'd like to know if all of these sentences are the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

They have different meaning and it depends on what is purpose by saying each.

First points to the place you saw the girl, the second and third point to the time. The place (*in which*) seems irrelevant to your clause because your focus is on the girl not the club.

2 or 3 are more relevant because they point that you found the girl attractive after seeing her dancing, in (3) you should say **At That moment**, because you point to a time in the past.

Comment: So, "comma in which" can only be used when to refer to a place right?

Comment: because you used if after *club* it normally refers to the *club*, specially you say *in which* means *in the club*.